# xcb: Asynchronous pointer grab not propagating events

Tags: linux, x11, xorg, xcb

I am trying to make an image appear under my cursor whenever I click on my desktop. I decided to use xcb to accomplish this. I figured I should capture the pointer from the root window (I don't really know a better way to do it), because I always want the image to appear, no matter where I click. The application that displays the image should not interfere with my normal workflow.

Here is how I capture the pointer so far:

```
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <X11/Xlib-xcb.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <xcb/xcb_aux.h>
#include <xcb/xcb.h>
#include <xcb/xproto.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <err.h>
void setup(xcb_connection_t *connection) {
    xcb_generic_error_t *err;
    xcb_screen_t *screen = xcb_setup_roots_iterator(xcb_get_setup(connection)).data;
    xcb_void_cookie_t grab_cookie = xcb_grab_button(connection, True, screen->root, XCB_NONE, XCB_GRAB_MODE_ASYNC, XCB_GRAB_MODE_ASYNC, XCB_NONE, XCB_NONE, XCB_BUTTON_INDEX_1, XCB_MOD_MASK_ANY);
    xcb_generic_error_t *error = xcb_request_check(connection, grab_cookie);
    if (error != NULL) {
        xcb_disconnect(connection);
        perror("could not subscribe to events on a window, bailing out");
        exit(1);
    }  
    free(error);
        xcb_flush(connection);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    xcb_generic_event_t *e;
    Display *dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    xcb_connection_t *connection = XGetXCBConnection(dpy);
    setup(connection);
    while ((e = xcb_wait_for_event(connection))) {
        switch(e->response_type & ~0x80) {
            case XCB_BUTTON_PRESS:
                printf("Click.\n");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        free(e);
    }
    xcb_ungrab_pointer(connection, XCB_TIME_CURRENT_TIME);
}
```

The code line that grabs the cursor is in the `setup` method:

```
 xcb_void_cookie_t grab_cookie = xcb_grab_button(connection, True, screen->root, XCB_NONE, XCB_GRAB_MODE_ASYNC, XCB_GRAB_MODE_ASYNC, XCB_NONE, XCB_NONE, XCB_BUTTON_INDEX_1, XCB_MOD_MASK_ANY);
```

As far as I can tell by "autocorrecting" `man xcb_grab_button`, my pointer events should not be influenced if I put `XCB_GRAB_MODE_ASYNC` as the fifth argument to the function (the manual says something different, but it is generally quite poor, so I would be very surprised if it weren't by mistake). However, this is not the case: When I click, the click simply gets swallowed by my application and, e.g., Firefox does not react to it.

How can grab the cursor such that my click events do not get eaten? If such a feature does not exist in X, would you recommend that I simply "resend" the click events or is there a better option? My window manager is i3, in case this information changes anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the mystery. Apparently `XCB_GRAB_MODE_ASYNC` does not do what I thought it would: The `xcb_grab_pointer` manual says that the pointer event processing continues normally. I thought that this would refer to the events being propagated to other clients, but this is not the case. The events are still only heard by my application. To propagate the events, they need to be replayed after receival:

```
xcb_generic_event_t *e;
xcb_generic_error_t *err;
xcb_connection_t *connection = xcb_connect(NULL, NULL);
xcb_screen_t *screen = xcb_setup_roots_iterator(xcb_get_setup(connection)).data;
xcb_void_cookie_t grab_cookie = xcb_grab_button_checked(connection, True, screen->root, XCB_EVENT_MASK_BUTTON_PRESS | XCB_EVENT_MASK_BUTTON_RELEASE, XCB_GRAB_MODE_SYNC, XCB_GRAB_MODE_ASYNC, XCB_NONE, XCB_NONE, XCB_BUTTON_INDEX_1, XCB_MOD_MASK_ANY);
xcb_generic_error_t *error = xcb_request_check(connection, grab_cookie);
if (error != NULL) {
    xcb_disconnect(connection);
    perror("could not subscribe to events on a window, bailing out");
    exit(1);
}  
free(error);
do {
    xcb_allow_events(connection, XCB_ALLOW_REPLAY_POINTER, XCB_CURRENT_TIME);
    e = xcb_poll_for_event(connection);
    if(!e) {
        continue;
    }
    switch(e->response_type & EVENT_MASK) {
        case XCB_BUTTON_RELEASE:
        case XCB_BUTTON_PRESS:
            printf("Hello.\n");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    free(e);
} while(1);
xcb_ungrab_pointer(connection, XCB_TIME_CURRENT_TIME);
```

Before the do-while-loop, the pointer press and release for the index1 button are grabbed. The fifth argument has to be `XCB_GRAB_MODE_SYNC` so that the X server queues events until `xcb_allow_events` is called (the Xlib manual, `man XGrabPointer`, gives detailed information, though I wouldn't rely on it in detail, given that it is not for XCB). The subsequent call to `xcb_allow_events` within the `while`-loop thaws (unfreezes) the pointer event processing. Passing the `XCB_ALLOW_REPLAY_POINTER` parameter replays the button events.

It's important to use `xcb_poll_for_event` within the loop, although I don't fully understand why.